# Python - struct.pack vs struck.packinto

Tags: python, pack

I am writing a program where i need to send lots of small chunks of data to a server (mostly integers or strings), so i am using the struct-library. 
Right now i am using `struct.pack`, but i am wondering if i should use `struct.pack_into` instead, as i read it reduces overhead.

However, i am not interested in "saving" the values- i just want to pack the data and quickly send it off. If i use `struct.pack_into`, would it save the values in any way as it uses a buffer, thus reducing performance?

Which of these 2 methods best suits my needs?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The difference between these methods really revolves around whether you already have an **existing** buffer you wish to write formatted data into (`struct.pack_into`), or whether you simply want to create a **new** buffer with the formatted data (`struct.pack`).

You are dealing with small buffers. Unless you have good reason to suspect you need to optimise for buffer copies, you may as well be using `struct.pack`